# are reactive properties accessed after the first await tracked by the watchEffect?

Tags: vue.js

in [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#watcheffect) tutorial, it is mentioned that

> watchEffect only tracks dependencies during its synchronous execution.
> When using it with an async callback, only properties accessed before the
> first await tick will be tracked.

but as for the example posted below and it is quoted from the aforementioned website, the `todoId.value` is accessed after the first `await`, though it is being tracked by the `watcher`
according to my understanding and referring the above quoted text, in order `todoId.value` to be tracked by the `watcher` it must be accessible before the firat `await`

please rectify my understanding to this issue

**code**:

```
watchEffect(async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${todoId.value}`
  )
  data.value = await response.json()
})
```

Comment: There's no way how this could be done in JS. "synchronous" is the keyword here. It could be tracked only if you add `data.value;` at the first line of the function

Comment: @EstusFlask sorry i could not understand what did you mean!would you please clarify farther

Comment: watchEffect calls a callback and checks which reactive properties were accessed at the end of *synchronous* execution. It physically can't take into account whatever happens after the first await. If you access data.value before await, it will be considered effect input, otherwise it won't

Comment: It is correct that only variables before `await` are watched. Your template string, which builds the final URL, is generated before `await`.  In other words, the fetch's argument must be ready before getting called. So, `todoId.value` is used before the async action.